# How can i use multer with react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I am build a web app with Node.js and React and I am trying to store some files at my backend.
For some reason i cant access to my req.path , although I configured all multer strategies.

```
const multer = require('multer')
const config = require('config')
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth')
const {check , validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file , cb){
        cb(null,'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, req.user.id)
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file , cb) =>{
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png')
    cb(null,false);
    else
    cb(null,true);
}
```

my route:

```
router.post('/' , [auth,upload.single('image'),
    [
    check('status','Status is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('skills','Skills is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('gender','Gender is required').not().isEmpty()
    ]],
    async (req,res) => {// cant access to req.file.....}
```

and my react form:

```
 <div className="form-group">
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Choose profile image" name="profileImage" value={image}/>
                   <input type="file" placeholder="Upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="image" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}/>
                   <small className="form-text">The image must not be bigger then 5MB and only JPG\JPEG\PNG types</small>
 </div>
```

Please , what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I have used multer in my backend application and this is how I have configured it and it works properly and stores required files in server file directory.

First, installing multer

```
 npm i multer --save
```

Second, initialize it at the top of required .js file

```
const multer = require("multer");
```

Now, configuring storage (storage location and filename)

```
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: "./public/uploads/postimages/",
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(
          null,
          file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
        );
      },
    });
```

Init multer function, (configure own file size)

Use array if you want to upload multiple files at once, 10 is the number of files, you can modify it as needed.

```
 const upload = multer({
      storage: storage,
      limits: { fileSize: 10000000000 },
    }).array("image", 10);
```

// Use .single("image"); if you want to upload a single file.
// image is the name/key that is sent from frontend with the file(s).

If you are using array, you can create an api that stores file, which will look like this.

```
  try {
    let imagePath = "abc";
    let postId = req.params.postId;
    let imagesLinks = [];

    await upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (req.files == undefined) {
          console.log("File not found.");
        } else {
          //image uploaded successfully

          req.files.map(function (file) {
            imagePath = "uploads/postimages/" + file.filename;
            imagesLinks.push(tmp);
          });
        }
      }
      res.status(201).send(imagesLinks);
    });
  }
```

For a single file, it looks as simple as this

```
 try {
    let imagePath = "abc";

    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(300).send(err);
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (req.file == undefined) {
          res.status(301).send("image upload failed.");
        } else {
          //image uploaded successfully
          imagePath = "uploads/" + req.file.filename;
          storeImageLink(res, imagePath);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: very nice and beautified explanation

Answer (score 0):

Look at these examples. They will be help you:

[File Upload With Multer in Node.js and Express](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088)

Multer Storage:

```js
// SET STORAGE
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
 
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Handling File Uploads:

```js
app.post('/uploadfile', upload.single('myFile'), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
  }
    res.send(file)
  
})
```

[Reactjs nodejs upload image — How to upload image using reactjs and nodejs (multer)](https://medium.com/@mahesh_joshi/reactjs-nodejs-upload-image-how-to-upload-image-using-reactjs-and-nodejs-multer-918dc66d304c)

Node.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: "./public/uploads/",
   filename: function(req, file, cb){
      cb(null,"IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
   }
});

const upload = multer({
   storage: storage,
   limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
}).single("myImage");
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/upload", {
   upload(req, res, (err) => {
      console.log("Request ---", req.body);
      console.log("Request file ---", req.file);//Here you get file.
      /*Now do where ever you want to do*/
      if(!err)
         return res.send(200).end();
   });
};);
```